# Class assigning index to object using static class variable

Tags: python, instantiation

I have a class which represents an object to be kept in a set. I would like the class itself to remember how many it has created so that when you call `SetObject()` and `__init__()` a new object is created, which receives a unique index. Maybe something like this

```
class SetObject(object):
  # static class variable 
  object_counter = 0

  def __init__(self, params):
    self.params=params
    self.index = self.get_index()

  def get_index(self):
    object_counter += 1
    return object_counter-1

a = SetObject(paramsa)
b = SetObject(paramsb)
print a.index
print b.index
```

would produce

```
0
1
```

or something like this. Currently it seems that this approach gives a "variable referenced before assignment" error.

Comment: Remember that objects need to be hashable if they go in a set, and they may not be mutable.

Comment: Not actually true. The state used to compute the object's __eq__ and __hash__ must be immutable. If you don't override a class'__eq__ and __hash__ than the object's id is used to deduce the hash. And since the object's id never changes (even if it's attributes change) => you can use it in a set without any problems.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to write:

```
  def get_index(self):
     SetObject.object_counter += 1
     return SetObject.object_counter-1
```

otherwise it would only work if object_counter was a global variable.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use a reference to the class to refer to it's variables; you could perhaps use a class method (with the `@classmethod` decorator), but there is really no need to.

Better use `itertools.count()` to get a fool-proof 'static' counter; no need to reassign back to the class attribute then:

```
import itertools

class SetObject(object):
   object_counter = itertools.count().next

   def __init__(self, params):
       self.params=params
       self.index = self.object_counter()
```

(code above assumes Python 2; on Python 3 iterables do not have a `.next` method and you'd need to use `functools.partial(next, itertools.count())` instead).

Because the counter is an iterator, we don't need to assign to `SetObject.object_counter` at all. Subclasses can provide their own counter as needed, or re-use the parent class counter.

Comment: Why not just use `self.index = self.object_counter()`? The class attribute is found automatically when there's no overriding instance attribute.

Comment: I'm not complaining about assigning to `self.index`. All I'm saying is that calling `self.__class__.object_counter()` is (in the absence of an instance attribute) exactly the same as the simpler `self.object_counter()`

Comment: @Duncan: Duh. Of course. Updated, thanks for waking me up this morning (need more caffeine, I guess).

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
object_counter += 1
```

translates to

```
object_counter = object_counter + 1
```

When you assign to a variable inside a scope (e.g. inside a function), Python assumes you wanted to create a new local variable. So it marks `object_counter` as being local, which means that when you try to get its value (to add one) you get a "not defined" error.

To fix it, tell Python where to look up `object_counter`. In general you can use the `global` or `nonlocal` keywords for this, but in your case you just want to look it up on the class:

```
self.__class__.object_counter += 1
```

Comment: I think SetObject.object_counter is cleaner than self.__class__.object_counter

Comment: @IoanAlexandruCucu I don't: it hardcodes and duplicates the name of the class. That breaks inheritance (a `class LoggedSetObject(SetObject)`, say) and refactoring (if you want to rename `SetObject`).

Comment: +1 for explaining what actually happens. But `nonlocal` only works in python 3, OP seems to be using python 2.